# C++ Program: read file and write file by VS Code in Ubuntu 16.04 can't find the file path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote a c++ example program in VS code on ubuntu 16. The example si to read file and write file. However, the compiler reports that it can not find the file path. I don' know what happened. Here is my **main.cpp** file:

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void test01(){
    char* filename ="/home/mark2/Desktop\\source.txt";
    ifstream ism(filename, ios::in); // only read function to open the file
    //ifstream ism;
    //ism.open(filename, ios::in);// only read function to open the file
if(!ism){
    cout<<"file open failed"<<endl;
}
//read file
char ch;
while(ism.get(ch)){
    cout<<ch;
}
//file has beem opened, now close the file
ism.close();

}

int main(){

test01();


    return 0;
}
```

And here is my launch.json file;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't what should I do to next. Could you please give me some advice?
Thanks!

Comment: `/home/mark2/Desktop\\source.txt` - that backslash looks mighty suspicious.

Comment: If this is the Win10 system, I think the path is okay. I don't know exactly how to read the file successfully.

Comment: `/home/mark2/Desktop\\source.txt` doesn't look like a valid Windows path to me.  Anyway, I'm confused.  Your post talks about (and is tagged) ubuntu.

Comment: It's only a valid Linux path if there is a file in `/home/mark2` with filename `Desktop\source.txt` (Yes, a backslash is allowed in filenames and foldernames). _"the compiler reports that it can not find the file path"_ Do you get an error in the compile step or after you run your program?

Comment: You can look at my main.cpp again, if the file path is correct, it can not print "file open failed". Actually, it prints this string.